# Powershell - alias for Array values?

Tags: arrays, powershell, alias

is it possible to use some short names / aliases for values in Array ?
For example, we must test connection to FDQN but we would like to display result as short names.

```
$array = @( "youtube.com" , "google.com" )

$result = test-connection $array -count 1 -asjob | receive-job -wait
$result | select Address,ResponseTime | sort-object -Property ResponseTime

write-host "Fastest server is: <alias> "
```

Aliases:
GG = google.com
YT = youtube.com

Comment: You can make a hashtable with the real site urls as the key and an “alias” as the value - e.g. ```$lookups = @{ “youtube.com” = “YT”; “google.com” = “GG” }``` and then ```write-host “fastest site = $($lookups[@($result)[0].Address])”```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2), the Keys would be the hosts to ping and and the Values would be the alias for each host:

```
$hash = @{
    'youtube.com' = 'GG'
    'google.com'  = 'YY'
}

$result = Test-Connection @($hash.Keys) -Count 1 -AsJob |
    Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

$sorted = $result | Select-Object Address, ResponseTime |
    Sort-Object -Property ResponseTime

$sorted | Format-Table

Write-Host ('Fastest server is: {0}' -f $hash[$sorted[0].Address])
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you !!!
Is it possible also to display full result of test-connection in table view ?
I tried Write-Host $sorted but it is listed in 1 row...

Comment: @jarodas2004 you mean like adding the alias? or just display the result before the "Fastest server..." message? If so, you can just output `$sorted` before the message (without `Write-Host`)

Comment: Unfortunately the result table is always displayed on the end, after the "Fastest server..."
It looks like 1 command do not wait for previous to finish..

Comment: @jarodas2004 use `Format-Table`, that will force it to be displayed first. `$sorted | Format-Table`